# Disable prompts while installing a Debian package

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, deb, non-interactive

How can I totally disable the prompts that appear while installing a Debian package? I've used all the options that I've found but there are some packages that are still prompting.

I'm using this command:

```
apt-get -y --allow-unauthenticated --force-yes -o DPkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confdef" install x11-common
```

Why is the `x11-common` package still prompting? How can I get rid of these prompts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide any details about what prompt this is, but I am guessing it is `debconf` prompting for configuration questions.

If so, you can set `debconf` to noninteractive mode. For example, by doing `dpkg-reconfigure debconf` and then it will use the defaults for everything.

Answer (score 6):

You need to tell `debconf` to use the `noninteractive` frontend, like this:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get -y --allow-unauthenticated --force-yes -o DPkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confdef" install x11-common
```

Comment: `man -s 7 debconf` says it's `DEBIAN_FRONTEND`, not `DEBCONF_FRONTEND`.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution to avoid prompts without necessarily accepting defaults is to use [preseeding](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed).  This means you populate the Debconf database with answers to the questions the package installation is going to ask, and then it won't ask because it gets the answers from the database.

You might still want to use an option to disable interactive prompting, just to be on the safe side.

(A lot of the preseeding documentation you find on the Internet is specifically about unattended system installation, but you can use preseeding for any individual package at any point before installing it.)

Comment: The near-duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331836/apt-get-install-tzdata-noninteractive has a good example of how to do this in practice.