# apt-get install tzdata noninteractive

Tags: bash, ubuntu, dockerfile, apt-get

When I try to

```
apt-get install -y tzdata
```

the command line option for picking timezone shows up. I am trying to use this in a script to do some setup, how can I make the apt-get run without user input?

I know to reconfigure the tzdata I can do

```
echo "America/New_York" > /etc/timezone
dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

But when installing I need it to run fully even if it doesn't set the right timezone, I can always reconfigure it.

I tried

```
echo 5 | apt-get install -y tzdata
```

but it is not working as expected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20693661/1174169, while marked as "off-topic" also answers this question, by creating a "pre-seed" text file with debconf settings, prior to running `apt-get install`. With this technique I was able to install tzdata non-interactively without any symlink workarounds.

Comment: UPDATE: just noticed the same answer from @freelance below, using debconf

Answer (score 313, accepted):

This is the script I used

**(Updated Version with input from @elquimista from the comments)**

```
#!/bin/bash

ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

Seems to work fine.

As one liner:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends tzdata
```

Comment: If you are fine with UTC, here's a one-liner: `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata`

Comment: This is such a pain. I can't install tzdata without it prompting me to set my default timezone (configuration prompt during package installation? whose idea was this?), and I can't set the default timezone without first installing tzdata. It already defaults to UTC if you pass in EOF. Why not just do that and let user update later if they want. Or let me set TZ environment variable and have tzdata look for that.

Comment: Doing `ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime` step before `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata` was the only way I could get this to install w/o a prompt.

Comment: Same goes for me, the only way this worked was by placing the ln statement first. @PYA.

Answer (score 159):

If someone wants to achieve it in `Dockerfile`, use as below.

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install tzdata
```

Comment: This can be done as a single line:
```RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ...```
The `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` variable must be set for the `install` part. It does not work if set before the `&&` for the `update` part.

Comment: Issuing `ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` on a separate line worked for me _sometimes_, while on a single line as recommended by @DanielStevens worked for me _always._

Comment: `ARG` is useful for when you have command-line arguments. You want `ENV` to set it unconditionally.

Comment: Setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` with `ENV` [should be actively discouraged](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4032#issuecomment-34597177). [Use `ARG` instead](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4032#issuecomment-192327844).

Comment: @StephanSamuel Glad I'm not the only one. What's the reason behind `ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` only working _sometimes_?

Comment: @StephanSamuel `ARG` variables only exist in the build stage they're declared in. I.e. they are ["cleared" by following `FROM` instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact).

Comment: Fixed it to be one line -- misc commenters are correct, that's how it should be done.

Answer (score 24):

To avoid playing directly with symlinks and to run configuration only once, I suggest to use [`debconf-set-selections`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/debconf/debconf-set-selections.1.en.html) command:

```
echo 'tzdata tzdata/Areas select Europe' | debconf-set-selections
echo 'tzdata tzdata/Zones/Europe select Paris' | debconf-set-selections
DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt install -y tzdata
```

Comment: This did not work for me in current ubuntu:latest

Comment: I test it again using the following Dockerfile and it seems to be ok. What is your issue?

`FROM ubuntu:latest`
`RUN echo 'tzdata tzdata/Areas select Europe' | debconf-set-selections`
`RUN echo 'tzdata tzdata/Zones/Europe select Paris' | debconf-set-selections`
`RUN apt update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt install -y tzdata`

Comment: I ended up doing the same that is now working. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

I have recently found the following solution in a Dockerfile building the [Cingulata](https://github.com/CEA-LIST/Cingulata/blob/157b4c66441e4e253e06a0abe1508976605100d8/Dockerfile.bfv#L12) FHE library:

```
ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$(curl https://ipapi.co/timezone) /etc/localtime
```

It basically uses the API provided by ipapi.co to retrieve the timezone information. This automatically configures the timezone properly instead of skipping the dialog and using the default (UTC).

Comment: Smart idea to use https://ipapi.co/timezone, provided that the timezone to set is same as where the machine is located. This may not work for e.g. with user in Asia, but server in US.

Answer (score 10):

All credit for this should go to @PYA but the right order should be:

```
ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get install -y tzdata
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I did it:

```
echo 1 > input.txt
echo 1 >> input.txt
apt-get install -y tzdata < input.txt
ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime
echo America/Los_Angeles > /etc/timezone
```

The first two echo statements create a text file that contains the selection numbers for the geographic area menu and the city/region menu. This file is then used to provide input to the apt-get install command. The tzdata package will be installed without asking for any user input. The timezone will be set to Africa/Abidjan as if you entered 1 and 1 in response to the prompts you would normally get. Then I change the timezone to what I want with the last two commands.

Instead of 1 and 1, you could use the actual numbers for the geographic area and city/region that you want, but it seems to me that those numbers could change.

Answer (score 3):

here is what worked for me:

```
from ubuntu:bionic
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata

RUN unlink /etc/localtime
RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments, I did two steps below to use the TZ environment variable:

- Added the following to the Dockerfile

```bash
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends tzdata && apt-get clean
```

- Added the following to the docker CMD script:

```bash
    if [ ! -z "${TZ}" ]; then
        echo "${TZ}" > /etc/timezone
        dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
    fi
```

This worked for me and allowed me to set the time zone when starting the container.