# Docker build stops on software-properties-common when run with `apt update`

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have 2 dockerfiles:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    python3
```

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3
```

The thing is: when I run the first of them (with `docker build`) the build process hangs on:

[image]

The `software-properties-common` package is asking me about the geographical area - I cannot provide any input, it is not allowed when building images, I suppose.

However, when I build the second dockerfile, this problem does not occur. I'm curious - why is that?

Answer (score 8):

Add the following line in your Dockerfile and build again.

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata
```

Comment: Ok, but why the second dockerfile does work fine, without that env `DEBIAN_FRONTEND`?

Comment: By the way, do you mean that I should install that exact package "tzdata" or was it just an example of how to set `DEBIAN_FRONTED` and I should actually ignore "tzdata"?

Comment: @Loreno I tried to build images using both the Dockerfiles you provided, but I could not reproduce the error. My build was successful in both. In your case, the build using second Dockerfile might be working due to layers from the previous builds.

Comment: I included the package tzdata because your docker build stops at configuring the time zone(tzdata). You can work without that as well.

Comment: I used `RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common python3` and unfortunately that didn't help. I'm still being asked for geographical location

Comment: I also tried `RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata software-properties-common python3.7` - still, the same problem occurs :(

Comment: @Loreno can you share your Dockerfile? I can have a look at it

Comment: @mnj `RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y tzdata && apt install -y -qq software-properties-common` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found that running

```
ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime
```

before setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` worked for me.  (You'd want to replace the bit after zoneinfo with whatever is applicable for you.)

If you need it to be set dynamically, [this answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63153978/1995015) suggests calling out to a website that can provide that.