# How to select an option when running Docker Build

Tags: docker

So I am running a docker build command from my command line..and it runs for a little bit and then waits at following prompt:

```
=> [ 4/19] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticat  3758.2s
 => => #   1. Africa        6. Asia            11. System V timezones
 => => #   2. America       7. Atlantic Ocean  12. US
 => => #   3. Antarctica    8. Europe          13. None of the above
 => => #   4. Australia     9. Indian Ocean
 => => #   5. Arctic Ocean  10. Pacific Ocean
 => => # Geographic area:
```

I am assuming that it is waiting for me to select a region. However no matter what I type in the command prompt, it does not proceed further.

I have tried options like `1`, `1.`, `#1`, `=>=>1` and all other weird things I can. Please help me, this is driving me crazy!! :)

Comment: Does this solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44333806/4676641?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks @tentative!