# Docker: gethostid returns 0 if container uses host network and vpn is up

Tags: c++, c, docker, glibc, ubuntu-20.04

[gethostid](https://linux.die.net/man/2/gethostid) behavior is different in a docker container if  I am connected to the VPN of my office.

Host OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Container OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Software used to connect to the VPN: SonicWall NetExtender 10.2.845 (also reproduced with 8.6.801)

Docker run command: `docker run -it --rm --network="host" test_gethostid_vpn:latest`

In this container gethostid takes 5 seconds to return 0.
The problem disappears if I remove --network="host" option or if I stop netExtender.

main.cpp which runs in my container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>

int main(int* argc, char** argv)
{
    auto startPoint = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    long hostid = gethostid();
    auto endPoint = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endPoint - startPoint).count();
    std::cout << "duration = " << duration << " [ms]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "hostid = " << hostid << std::endl;
    std::cout << "errno = " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(test_gethostid)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(test_gethostid main.cpp)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Non interactive apt
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331836/apt-get-install-tzdata-noninteractive
ENV TZ=Europe/Paris
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y cmake build-essential

COPY . /testcpp

WORKDIR /testcpp/build

RUN cmake ..
RUN make -j $(nproc)

ENTRYPOINT [ "./test_gethostid" ]
```

Comment: Probable cause: "In the glibc implementation, if gethostid() cannot open the file containing the host ID, then it obtains the hostname using gethostname(2), passes that hostname to gethostbyname_r(3) in order to obtain the host's IPv4 address, and returns a value obtained by bit-twiddling the IPv4 address."

Comment: What are your requirement for this host id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by sharing /etc/hostid with the container:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /etc/hostid:/etc/hostid --network="host" test_gethostid_vpn:latest
```